# How can we handle out of memory error?

Tags: height, width, out-of-memory

How can we handle out of memory error?

One of our customers contacted us and said when he uploads images, face with this error

> out of memory

I asked about size of images he said 4MB, but I could upload even a 7 MB image successfully.

So I tried to upload big images until I faced the error, most of them uploaded successfully but I faced the same error when uploading some of them

I found that error was not related in size of image, it's related to width and height of image

You can understand better by look at this link

[memory error](http://www.auxiliarycentral.com/tutes/PSHOP-save-for-web.pdf)

but I don't know what exactly `max-width` and `max-height` are, that I can validate to prevent this error.

I forgot to say, also I resize images dynamically.

But I can't say to users resize your images because them take large pictures with their phone but maybe some of them didn't know how can resize images with photoshop.

please help

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally you should restructure your code to use less memory.

There are ways to decrease the memory overflow for any JVM process.

- just give the JVM more memory with the -Xmx option.
- You should decode with [inSampleSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) option to reduce memory consumption.
- Another option inJustDecodeBounds can help you to find correct [inSampleSize](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bd858a63563a6d4a) value
- Also have a look over this [article](http://www.readwritejava.com/?qa=88/how-will-we-handle-out-of-memory-error-in-java)